# Two Dimensional Array Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Can any one explain this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void FunPrinter(int *x)
{
 int i, j;
 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++, printf("\n"))
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   printf("%d\t",*x++);
}

int main()
{
 int x[][5] = {
        {17, 5, 87, 16, 99},
        {65, 74, 58, 36, 6},
        {30, 41, 50, 3, 54},
        {40, 63, 65, 43, 4}
       };
 int i, j;
 int **xptr = x;
 printf("Addr:%ld,Val:%ld,ValR:%ld",(long int)x,(long int)*x,(long int)**x);
 printf("\nInto Function\n");
 FunPrinter(&x[0][0]);
 printf("\nOut Function\n");
 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++, printf("\n"))
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   printf("%d\t",**xptr++);
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Addr:140734386077088,Val:140734386077088,ValR:17
Into Function
17  5   87  16  99  
65  74  58  36  6   
30  41  50  3   54  
40  63  65  43  4   

Out Function
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why Direct Addressing is not working? I am accessing through pointers. I have used double pointer but it's not working.
I have also tried to use single pointer as xptr. But still not working.

Comment: Also, why (long int)x and (long int)*x have same value?

Comment: The syntax of the first "for" in each section is absolutely dreadful! Drop it now if you do not want to be beaten up by future programming co-workers.

Comment: @jpinto3912 Can you mark the problems please?

Comment: It's legal syntax, but very unusual. A seasoned programmer will know it is ok, but will still find it odd that you placed cycle operations within the control section of the statement. You're allowed to comma separate any number of instructions, but it makes it less readable. So my advise: for(init; compare; inc/decrement){ operation if compare OK}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a segmentation fault, because you are iterating over the wrong pointer (over the outermost dimension pointer). There are only 4 valid blocks on that dimension you can iterate over (not 20).

Here, `x` and `*x` (use `%p` to print pointers, not casting) are the same value, because they both point to the beginning of the array (same address), but the pointer arithmetic's are different (the size of element is different). You can iterate via `x` possibly needing to cast it to `int *`.

Also, the approach you are using in the `FunPrinter` - degrading a 2D array into 1D array is not guaranteed to work, it does indeed involve undefined behavior (although most reasonable compilers will compile this just fine).

Comment: Actually I know that a 2D array is basically a 1D array in memory. So, I have used that concept in FunPrinter.

But Can you explain the thing `x` and `*x` a little. and what is happening to `xptr`?
I will be highly obliged to know.

Comment: `int *xptr = &x;
 
 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++, printf("\n"))
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   printf("%d\t",*xptr++);
`

Now, this is printing my output. But gives a warning:
TwoDi.c:20:14: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Comment: @soham.m17 That's because you are not supposed to do this. Again, degrading a 2D array into 1D does involve undefined behavior. As for `x` and `*x`, they simply have the same value, the address of the beginning of the array. I don't really know what more to tell you.

Comment: What I want to do is to iterate over the array via pointer only.

I understand `x` and `*x` have the value of the address of the beginning of the array i.e &x[0][0]

Comment: @soham.m17 There's no problem in that, but you need to switch between the inner and the outer dimension.

Comment: But which is right?
`int **xptr = x;`
or
`int *xptr = x;`
or
`int *xptr = &x;`

What is the meaning of each of these?

Sorry if I am creating unnecessary situations...

Comment: @soham.m17 The first one represents a pointer to the beginning of the array, the rest is wrong code.

Comment: @soham.m17 Actually, sorry, the first one is also wrong. The correct one would be: `int (*xptr)[5] = x;`

Comment: And how to iterate using xptr?
And Why `int *xptr = &x` is an error but giving right output?
And I understand that x is representing a pointer-to-pointer to int.
and xptr is pointer-to an integer-array of size 5.
Am I right?

Comment: @soham.m17 Asking why a wrong code is giving you good results is on the same level as asking why it is raining outside when you sacrifice a goat. The correct code would look something like this: https://gist.github.com/3780717

Comment: :D Thanks. Can it be done by incrementing the pointer only?
Actually what is the xptr, now? and what will I get incrementing it?

Comment: @soham.m17 In the code I posted, `xptr` is a pointer to an array of 3 ints. By incrementing it, you will move to the next array of 3 ints in the array of arrays of 3 ints.

Comment: Got it perfectly.
Thanks for tolerating the pain. :P